# Encode the string by removing char from middle

Tags: c, string

I need to encrypt the algorithm as follows

**Algortihm :**

Initially encoded string will be empty. Given an String, Each time the middle char of string will be picked, and appened to encoded string.
Ie if string is `sanji`, First n will be picked.
EncodedStr will be `"n"`, Remaning message is `"saji"`, "a" will be picked (In case of even letters, left most middle will be picked)
EncodedStr will be "na", Remaining message is "sji"."j" will be picked.
Encoded Str is `"naj"`, Remaining Msg is "si". "s" will be picked. followed by i.Final encoded str will be `"najsi"`, and reverse follows for decoding.

Here is my code for encoding and decoding:

```
char * encode(char *str) {
    if (str == NULL)
        return NULL;
    int len = findLen(str);
    int temp = len;
    if (len == 1)
        return str;
    int k = 0;
    int mid = 0,i;
    int repl_chr = 'A';
    char * en = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*len);
    while (len > 0){
        mid = len / 2;
        en[k] = str[mid];
        k++;
        for (i = mid; i < len; i++){
            str[i] = str[i + 1];
        }
        len--;

        //memmove(&str[mid], &str[mid + 1], temp - mid);

    }
    printf("%s",en);
    return en;
}
char* decode(char *str) {
    if (str == NULL)
        return NULL;
    int len = findLen(str);
    if (len == 1)
        return str;
    char * en = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*len);
    return NULL;
}

int findLen(char *str){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++){}
    return i;
}
```

I have few bugs in my code.Can anyone help me to fix the bugs?

Comment: You need to explain the problems you're having, not just say "I have a few bugs in my code".

Comment: What is `findLen()`, why don't you use the standard `strlen()`?

Comment: [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: It's not a good idea to sometimes return a new string, and sometimes return the original string. The caller needs to know whether they should free the result or not. So you should always allocate a new string, even if it's just a copy of the original.

Comment: You should allocate `len+1` bytes, to allow space for the null terminator. And you need to add a null terminator to `en`.

Comment: Instead of removing characters from the string, you can simply copy `str[mid]`, then `str[mid-1]`, then `str[mid+1]`, `str[mid-2]`, `str[mid+2]`, etc. until you've copied everything.